# jQuery, setTimeout after button text is changed

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, settimeout

I have managed to change the text on my `Add to bag` button to `ADDED` after a click. It works fine with the following jQuery code, but I am wondering:

How can I revert the `ADDED` text back to the original text `Add to bag` after 5 seconds.

Am I missing something when using `setTimeout`? Or perhaps it is not the right way to approach this at all?

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added" ).text("ADDED");
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is exactly what you need. If you could show what you tried in the question we can help to show you what the issue is. I'm sure someone will be along shortly to just dump code for you, but I'd rather at least try to educate for future reference

Comment: Try to create a function that reset the value and just do `setTimeout(yourfunction, 5000);` after you change the value the first time

Comment: Thanks! I have used Bejado's code and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/window.setTimeout) method.

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var element = jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added");
    element.text("ADDED");
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.text("Add to bag");
    }, 5 * 1000);
});
```

After 5 seconds it will invoke the code inside the innermost `function()` block and change the text to "Add to bag".

Comment: ©Bejado, Could you please help with giving a hover background color to  element.text(''Add to bag'') ? It is reverting back and working but the hover effect is not reverting, I would like to also revert the button back to its normal hover background color. Thank you!

Comment: Miraj if you need additionally help, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to add is `setTimeout(function,x)` this will wait x amount of time before executing the function.

In this case we can use **5000** for 5 seconds and the function `jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added" ).text("Add to bag");` to change the text back.

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added" ).text("ADDED");
  setTimeout(function(){ jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added" ).text("Add to bag");}, 5000)
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your welcome, dont forget to upvote any answer that worked for you and accept the one that solve it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info Gerardo! unfortunately, I am new here and the system is not accepting my upvotes. I guess i need more reputation :)

Comment: @Miraj no worries. Welcome to SO and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I need a little more help with the above code, should I ask a new question or just update the existing one? what is the best way to get a support in this case? really appreciate your time :)

Comment: @Miraj It deppends. If the questions is related to the original problem and with the answer. You should comment to the answerer so he/I can help you. If its something new, I will recommend a new post, so you can get more people involved. You can even post a comment in the previous answer so people can go and help you there.

Comment: Thanks again. It is related and about the hover effect, Do you mean i can post it here in this comments for instance? sorry I sound so weird :)

Comment: @Miraj no worries. Why don't you tell me whats the problem so I can help you. Usually if no one is answering, that might be a sign to repost jajaja

Comment: Awesome! So, the Added text is reverting back to its original Add to bag text but not to the original/normal css hover background color. 

The original button has hover background color and the Added has its own hover color. 

after element.text(''Add to bag'') I tried element.css.hover('background-color', 'blue') and it is not working

Comment: jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var element = jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added");
    element.text("ADDED");
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.text("ADD TO BAG");
  element.css.hover('background-color', 'blue');
  element.css.hover('color', '#A9885D');
    }, 5 * 1000);
});

Comment: In this case the best way to go is by adding a class. Also this could be a new question

Comment: Yep! about to post haha :)